# URL Decoder c# asp.net

Tags: c#, url, query-string

In a **QueryString** I have a part that looks like this

```
...u4w51EEcg8%2bj04e7C....
```

When I am using **HttpUtility.UrlDecode** the part "%2b" which represents a "+"  just turns into a white space.
I'm using **HttpUtility.UrlEncode** in the first place to encode the string.

Does anyone have any clue to what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you decoding twice? For convenience, a `+` sign in a URL decodes to  (space, 0x20). While `%2b` should decode to `+`, decoding that will give you .

EDIT: Just saw your self-answer, and yeah, always check whether your getter functions / properties automatically decode for you. Double-decoding usually doesn't produce the desired result, and can even lead to security risks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that "Request.QueryString[]" decodewhatever it gets, so what happened was that I decode the QueryString 2 times, which makes "+" a whitespace.